# Custom Decorator over Dash CallBack

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to understand if it is possible to use dash callback with custom decorators.
Basic Dash App:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder_unfiltered.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Title of Dash App', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(df.country.unique(), 'Canada', id='dropdown-selection'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-content')
])

@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-selection', 'value')
)
def update_graph(value):
    dff = df[df.country==value]
    return px.line(dff, x='year', y='pop')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Function that I want to use as decorator:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        begin = time.time()
        func(*args,  **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print("Total time taken in : ", func.__name__, (end - begin))
    return wrapper_function
```

I tried to do the following:

```
@my_decorator
@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-selection', 'value')
)
def update_graph(value):
    dff = df[df.country==value]
    return px.line(dff, x='year', y='pop')
```

This one updated the dashboard, but it didn't print total time

```
@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-selection', 'value')
)
@my_decorator
def update_graph(value):
    dff = df[df.country==value]
    return px.line(dff, x='year', y='pop')
```

This one prints time, but the dashboard is not updated.

I need dashboard to update and time of callback to be printed. Python seems to support chained decorators, but it doesn't seem possible with @callback. Is there a way to do it? Or should I just copy/paste to each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning the result of the function you're decorating inside your decorator's inner function (`wrapper_function`).

Since you're not returning something explicitly, `wrapper_function` implicitly returns `None`. Essentially you're returning `None` for output `Output('graph-content', 'figure')` so you get an empty figure.

With your second callback attempt you can see that this is happening if you look in the network tab of your browser. The time is printed in the console and a request to `_dash-update-component` is made so both functions are being executed.

You could store the result in a variable and return it after you print the time taken:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        begin = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print("Total time taken in : ", func.__name__, (end - begin))
        return result
    return wrapper_function
```

Now this works:

```
@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-selection', 'value')
)
@my_decorator
def update_graph(value):
    dff = df[df.country==value]
    return px.line(dff, x='year', y='pop')
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Sorry for a late response!